# Exception in run Akka (Scala)

Tags: akka

I begin learning Akka with Scala. I have import lib akka-actor_2.10-2.3.10 and typesafe-config-2.10.1 to my project.
However, it thows exception when run.
Detail:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.config.Config.getDuration(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
    at akka.util.Helpers$ConfigOps$.akka$util$Helpers$ConfigOps$$getDuration$extension(Helpers.scala:126)
    at akka.util.Helpers$ConfigOps$.getMillisDuration$extension(Helpers.scala:121)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:505)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
    at com.livepass.thiendp.scala.akka.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(HelloActor.scala:22)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at com.livepass.thiendp.scala.akka.Main$.main(HelloActor.scala:21)
    at com.livepass.thiendp.scala.akka.Main.main(HelloActor.scala)
```

Please help me.

Comment: I didnt check what is the error, but I would suggest you to use Typesafe activator to start learning Akka. It is very simple and easy. http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-akka

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed.
When I use akka-actor_2.10-2.1.4, it run OK.

Comment: That will use Akka 2.1.4 which is a very old version. You want to go with version 2.3.10. Please note that the string "_2.10-2.1.4" contains first the scala version, and then the Akka version. I don't see a typesafe-config version 2.10.1 on Maven: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error, but changing akka-actor jar versions did not solve it. What worked was adding the typesafe config 1.3 jar:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe/config/1.3.0-M1

Hope that helps someone.